# iphone thread sync

Tags: iphone, multithreading, synchronization

I am java developer and need to make thread synch in iPhone. I have a thread, it calls other one and need to wait for that child thread to end.
In java I use monitor, by calling wait/notify

How can I program this in iphone?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

NSConditionLock does all job

Answer (score 0):

Read about [`NSOperation` dependencies](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004591-RH2-SW14) and also [`NSNotification`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSNotification) notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer pthreads. To block for a thread to complete, you want `pthread_join` Alternately, you could set up a `pthread_cond_t` and have the calling thread wait on that until the child thread notifies it.

```
void* TestThread(void* data) {
    printf("thread_routine: doing stuff...\n");
    sleep(2);
    printf("thread_routine: done doing stuff...\n");
    return NULL;    
}

void CreateThread() {
    pthread_t myThread;
    printf("creating thread...\n");
    int err = pthread_create(&myThread, NULL, TestThread, NULL);
    if (0 != err) {
        //error handling
        return;
    }
    //this will cause the calling thread to block until myThread completes.
    //saves you the trouble of setting up a pthread_cond
    err = pthread_join(myThread, NULL);
    if (0 != err) {
        //error handling
        return;
    }
    printf("thread_completed, exiting.\n");
}
```